# Will the centre of mass of this setup will remain at rest if the force to compress the spring is vanished?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring

Assume a equilateral triangular shape body of mass M its attached to its vertices by three springs which is connected to ground . Now after equilibrium is acheived if someone makes a vertex point go below equilibrium length (compressed a bit) by applying some force vertically and then removing that force will the centre of mass of the body will stay at rest and not move anywhere ? What will be happen if the vertical force is applied to midpoint of one side and then released? Will then also centre of mass of body will not move at all and so perform oscillations about its COM? (My thinking even after releasing the force body still has external force acting by the springs so centre will definitely will not be at rest but i am not sure ].[image]

Comment: A diagram would be helpful. It's not clear where this body is positioned with respect to ground, what "body of mass M is attached to its vertices" means (do you mean the body is attached to the ground by three springs at the vertices?), or what "eqb" means. Consider reviewing the Wikipedia page on [harmonic oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator), which occurs when a spring–mass system is perturbed. [The corresponding (damped) motion is shown here](http://john.maloney.org/Programming/boing_components.gif).

Comment: Added image Sir initially its plane is horizontal only and then its disturbed from its equilibrium(eqb) position. From one vertex or one side midpoint from vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system starts in equilibrium. If you compress/extend any of the spring and then release them, the system will go back to the same equilibrium. If the center of mass moved between the initial equilibrium state and the perturbed state, then the COM will move back from the perturbed state position to the equilibrium state position when released.

Compressing any of the springs will move the COM downwards, so when released, the COM will move back upwards and oscillate around the equilibrium point. The only way the COM doesn't move at all is if it doesn't move when you perturb the system, which you could achieve by compressing one spring and extending another, for example.

Comment: I agree Sir giving a vertical force will move the COM downwards , consider this force is applied at a midpoint of its side(BC) , what will be the reasoning which tells that the third vertexA portion will not move up a bit by itself ? [ Like we have when we consider a rod getting a force at one end the other end moves by itself isnt ? ]

Answer (score 1):

When released, each point will undergo [harmonic oscillation](http://john.maloney.org/Programming/pythonboing.htm) around its equilibrium point (assuming ideal springs; link goes to a page of animations I made to visualize this motion):

[image]

For this block attached to a single spring, only a single degree of freedom exists. However, since a plate attached to three springs can translate in the z direction but also rotate around at least two additional axes (looking at it horizontally, it can both [pitch and roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_principal_axes)), it constitutes a [multi-degree-of-freedom](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec19.pdf) system that can undergo different [modes of vibration](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/mclaskey/vib/struct/Koppi/modesOfVibrations.html) depending on the initial loading; some points (called [nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_(physics))) may remain motionless. As you note, the motion is driven by the net force applied by the springs after the load is removed.

The initial stationary displacement from an arbitrary load can be determined by drawing a [free-body diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram) and performing a [statics analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statics).

Comment: Sir thanks i was having doubt of just if one side goes down by a force will the other end point goes up ? Like that happens in case of a rod , if that is not taking place here why so ? This is the question i was asking